# Service Fabric IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody Iterate Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

*Edited* left name of a custom type instead of the direct service fabric interface.

I am trying to write an interceptor capable of interrogating the parameters being passed to a remoting service. I can intercept the IServiceRemotingRequestMessage once it gets to the service and am able extract the parameters, but ONLY if I know the position and name of the parameter at the time.
[Pseudo]
var someParam = IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody.GetParameter(0, "request", serviceRequestInfo.RequestMessage.GetBody().GetType());

What I need is a way to simply iterate the parameters and work with them directly (currently just serialize them to a string so I can log some of the info being passed). However, the IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody only exposes a GetParameter method that must be passed the index and the name...

I can maybe do some reflection work given the method name and the service contract but I'm hoping there is a much more straightforward way to get this directly.

Thanks for any tips,
Will

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way using the default serialization, but the way I solved it, currently, is to replace the Service Fabric serialization providers with JSON Serialization. Then, my interceptors can work with the JSON data as necessary.

I'll assume there is a way to do something similar with the default serialization but, if so, it's not clearly documented how to work with it. If someone proposes an option I would gladly give it a try.